# How does one pluralize hyphenated compounds constructed from phrases?

Tags: grammatical-number

In light of the highly regular pluralization in English, compound phrases are instinctively pluralized by likewise adding an s. For example, a parent might say to a child, "I'm really sick of hearing your constant I-didn't-do-its!" I have seen this sort of hyphenated compound construction in German in the translations of the Harry Potter books; e.g., du-weißt-schon-wer for you-know-who. But this is, of course, singular. Given the irregularity of German pluralization, how, in general are similar compounds made plural?

Comment: _+s_ is the fallback plural morph. It’s employed for xenisms, acronyms and can usually be applied here, too. Phrasal compounds aren’t that idiomatic in German, though.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it just the same way as in english: pluralize the last part of the compound:

> Ich habe genug von deinen "Ich-wars-nicht"s!
>
> Du-weisst-schon-wers

But i actually never hear it. Germans do not use such constructions too often. Instead, a paraphrase is used:

> Ich habe genug von deinen Ausreden!

Comment: I wouldn't do it. I would use singular. "Ich hab genug von deinem ewigen Ich-war-es-nicht."

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is one way, that will always work, but let me suggest how I would translate your example using a compound:

```
Ich habe genug von deinen dauernden Ich-war-es-nicht.
```

Compare it to

```
Ich habe genug von deinem dauernden Ich-war-es-nicht.
```

*deinen* shows the following is plural, while *deinem* shows singular. This works here, but could fail for other hyphenated compunds.

---

As @marstato said, Germans would probably use a paraphrase here.

Answer (score 1):

I think that such phrases with hyphens are used seldom. The thing I just remember is: Hanns Guck-in-die-Luft (Struwwelpeter), but then it is a replacement for a name and not a quotation used as a noun. I would write it just with quotes and without hyphens:

```
Ich habe genug von deinem ständigen "Ich war es nicht".
```

In this case I would prefer singular.